# Android cannot re-size LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I've been working on an android application recently, and in the last day or so I've been working on the GUI using the eclipse layout editor. Unfortunately, I can't resize my linearlayout in any way other than the x-dimension. I can also resize it by resizing the TextView contained within it. As sushil stated, I can't control the height of my linearlayout. My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/helpLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/InfoTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Info:"
                android:textSize="35sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Add  `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
```

Comment: That appears to have done the trick. Thank you! EDIT: Nope, Now I can't move my textview at all.

Comment: You should keep using `match_parent` instead of the deprecated `fill_parent`

Comment: @dylanisawesome1 what do you mean you can't move it?

Comment: when i attempt to move it, it pops back to where it was before.

Answer (score -2):

I don`t know if I understood what you want, but try to change this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

this way, it will fill the screen when size is different.

Comment: This is a bad idea since [fill_parent is deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT), and replaced by match_parent